# roslaunch giving this message ,please suggest something

Tags: ros, roslaunch, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch sender sender_node
... logging to /home/haneesh/.ros/log/3f3a9790-8022-11e7-a9cc-780cb88742bd/roslaunch-haneesh-ubuntu-366.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268705/roslaunch-giving-this-message-,please-suggest-something/) by [eghan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31564/eghan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-13**:
This is not a question, this is a dump of the console output of `roslaunch`. Please see [Guidelines for asking a question](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29) and update your post.

**Comment by [eghan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31564/eghan/) on 2017-08-14**:
i got the solution for it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslaunch is trying to tell you that there is a syntax error in your launch file.

If you edit your question and paste the contents of your launch file, we can probably help you find it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eghan](https://answers.ros.org/users/31564/eghan/) on 2017-08-14**:
got he solution for it.thank you :)